# CodeIgniter - Unable to get debug error log

Tags: php, codeigniter

using codeigniter in my controller I have the below but its not appearing in my logs. I have set in config.php logging to 4. Is there something else I am missing? $data in the same function is currently set as $data = 12345.

The function does work as it performs action I tell it but I wanted to see it in the logs for debugging.

log_message('debug',print_r($data,TRUE));

Thanks

Comment: Is the log folder writeable?

Comment: yes there are logs going into the file.

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 41M Apr  6 21:43 /var/log/httpd/ssl_error_log

Comment: I was looking in the wrong place..lol I was checking /var/log/ssl_error_log instead of /var/www/html/web/application/log/log

Answer (score 0):

I was looking in the wrong place..lol I was checking /var/log/ssl_error_log instead of /var/www/html/web/application/log/log